# Login page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem: I need to check if the username typed into an input form is equal to the username that is in my array of users. I do the same thing for password. I want to make a login form.

```
var app = angular.module('myApplication', []);

app.controller('UserListCtrl', function ($scope) {   
  $scope.usersList = [    
      {
          name: 'Alex',
          pass: 2200201
      },
      {
          name: 'Michael',
          pass: 1231215   
      },
      {
          name: 'John',
          pass: 1232116   
      }
  ];

  $scope.checkInputs = function () {

      $scope.searchUser = {
          name: $scope.yourName,
          pass: $scope.yourPass
      };

      if ($scope.searchUser.name === $scope.usersList.name) {
          console.log($scope.searchUser.name);
      } else {
          console.log('You are not registered');
      }

  };
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="checkInputs()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourName"><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourPass">
        <input type="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, what is the problem you're having with this code?

Comment: @Juhana, code dosn't work :(
It shows me "undefined" in console and dosn't check anything

Comment: Is it because you have `$scope.searchUser.name` in the controller and `searchUser.yourName` in the view?

Comment: `$scope.usersList` is...a list. Therefore `$scope.usersList.name` does not make sense in your condition.

Comment: @Juhana,  i thought  `searchUser.yourName`  will put in `searchUser.name`

Comment: Why would it do that?

Comment: No point having a login if you are going to expose all the user names and passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is your working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/g36hnc54/)

```
 <form  ng-submit="checkInputs(searchUser)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourName"><br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourPass">
            <input type="submit" class="button">
    </form>        



function formCtrl($scope){
         $scope.usersList = [    
          {
              name: 'Alex',
              pass: 2200201
          },
          {
              name: 'Michael',
              pass: 1231215   
          },
          {
              name: 'John',
              pass: 1232116   
          }
      ];

         $scope.checkInputs = function (credentials) {
             var auth = false;
             angular.forEach($scope.usersList, function(value){

                 if(value.name == credentials.yourName && value.pass == credentials.yourPass){
                     auth = true;
                 }
                 if(!auth){

                     $scope.message= "You are not authorized";

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $scope.message= "Authorized";
                 }

             });

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Important note* : this answer deals with the different mistakes that are present in the specific code posted in the question, as

- check if a string is contained in an array of object
- angularjs databinding between the view and the model

The code exposed here should not be considered as a valid authentication solution

---

> I need to check if username that the user types in input form is **equal to username that is in the array of users**

To achieve that, you wrote `$scope.searchUser.name === $scope.usersList.name`. That will fail, as `userList` is not a string but an array of strings. So as to check if a name is in the `userList` array, you can use the function [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

> The indexOf() method returns **the first index at which a given element can be found** in the array, **or -1 if it is not present**.

**1) Replace :**

```
if ($scope.searchUser.name === $scope.usersList.name) {
    // ...
}
```

with

*Solution 1 : assuming you use a library like lodash or underscore with a `pluck` function :*

```
var userNames = _.pluck($scope.usersList, 'name');
if (userNames.indexOf($scope.searchUser.name) >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

*Solution 2 : define yourself a `pluck` function :*

```
var myPluck = function (propertyName, array) {
    return array.map(function(obj) {
        return obj[propertyName];
    })
}
var userNames = myPluck('name', $scope.usersList);
if (userNames.indexOf($scope.searchUser.name) >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

**2) Replace also :**

```
$scope.searchUser = {
    name: $scope.yourName,
    pass: $scope.yourPass
};
```

with

```
$scope.searchUser = {
    name: '',
    pass: ''
};
```

**3) Finally, in the html template, replace :**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourName"><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.yourPass">
```

with

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.name"><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser.pass">
```

Comment: What is the value of `$scope.searchUser.name` just before the evaluation of the `if` statement? If you are not familiar with the debugger, put a `console.log($scope.searchUser.name);`

Comment: `$scope.searchUser.name` is undefined before the evaluation, i want to bind input form and `$scope.searchUser.name` with `ng-model`

Comment: Because the input name is binded with `searchUser.yourName` instead of `searchUser.name`. I completed the answer